# Why doesn't react update the style in the setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, inline-styles

Why doesn't react update the style in the setState? The color of the text does not update to green with the setState function, it remains blue.

```
class Practice extends Component {

    state = {
        count: 0,
        color: "blue"
    }

    style = {
        color: this.state.color
    }



    handleIncrement = () => {
        this.setState({ count: this.state.count});
        this.setState({ color: "green"});
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1 style={this.style}>
                    The color in this state is {this.state.color}. 
                    The number in count is {this.state.count}.
                    <button
                    onClick={this.handleIncrement}
                    >
                    Increment 
                    </button>
                </h1>
            </div>
        );
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While other answers explain well why your code is not working in terms of React state, there is one thing I noticed that might be another point of confusion.

When you're assigning a value to your `style` property like this:

```
style = {
    color: this.state.color
}
```

you might be thinking that you're assigning `style.color` a "reference" to the string that `this.state.color` points to. What *actually* happens is that you're assigning the value `"blue"`, because the string is a primitive type in JS. So after you've done that, your `style` object is really just

```
{
    color: "blue"
}
```

So even if you somehow change the value of `this.state.color`, this fundamentally wouldn't result in updating the value of `this.style.color`.

Comment: Yes, that's where my confusion was coming from. What I don't understand though is if setState calls the render function, the entire block of code that gets rerendered and returned. Wouldn't this.style re-call this.state.color and then it would be green?

Comment: @Devin your style assignment happens in the field initializer (which is analogous to putting it into the constructor), so outside of render(). In your render() you're only looking at current value of the style property

Answer (score 3):

Information on how a component should render should flow from state alone - this will allow you to call `setState` to change how the component renders. Putting a `.style` property on the component instance itself won't work - put it into the state instead.

Rather than duplicating the color in different parts of the state, put it in just one place, in the `style` object in state.

Not 100% certain, but you also probably want

```
this.setState({ count: this.state.count});
```

to be

```
this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
```

```js
class Practice extends React.Component {
    state = {
        count: 0,
        style: {
          color: 'blue',
        }
    }

    handleIncrement = () => {
        this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
        this.setState({ style: {
          ...this.state.style,
          color: "green"
        }});
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1 style={this.state.style}>
                    The color in this state is {this.state.style.color}. 
                    The number in count is {this.state.count}.
                    <button
                    onClick={this.handleIncrement}
                    >
                    Increment 
                    </button>
                </h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Practice />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`state` in react app will only update using `setState` if and only if you have inclued the state in `this.state` if you are using `constructor` or `state` property without `constructor`.

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

You should create state as:

```
state = {
    count: 0,
    style: {
      color: "blue"
    }
  };
```

and update the state as:

```
handleIncrement = () => {
    this.setState((oldState) => {
      return {
        count: oldState.count + 1,
        style: {
          ...oldState.style,
          color: "green"
        }
      };
    });
  };
```